# local notification not firing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This may be a repeated question,but please help me.I used the code below for firing a local notifification,but it is not firing.I used a picker to set the time for firing the local notification.Please help me..

```
[self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
if (nil != self.data) {
     //send data picker message
     [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.selectedIndex]];
} 
else {              
     //NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
     //NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     //[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss zzz"];
     //NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

     //send date picker message
     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];



     // Get the current date
     NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePickerView date];



    //NSLog(@"date ==%@",pickerdate);
    //Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                             fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                       fromDate:pickerDate];



    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    //NSLog(@"day%@",[dateComponents day]);
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];




    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
       return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    NSLog(@"%@what is this",itemDate);

    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];



    //Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Tip of the day";

    //Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";



    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;



    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;



    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
   localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

 // Schedule the notification

   [localNotif release];
}
```

Comment: When you copy-pasted code from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785989/local-notification-not-firing-in-iphone. You missed `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];`

Comment: Plus the notification also wont appear if your app is in the foreground

Comment: @xs2bush Sorry, I didn't see your comment getting posted, before I posted my answer.

Comment: @miamk no issues. Its good that you explained :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the code for scheduling the `local notification`?

You have to make this call somewhere before you release your `UILocalNotification` object:

```
- (void)scheduleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Like so,

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: localNotif];
```

Its only after you call this method that your `notification` gets copied, and hence safe for releasing the notification object.